# Open Layers: fill polygon not truly transparent, more like white with opacity

Tags: polygon, openlayers, fill

As you can see in the image, the color is not 'transparent', it just looks like open layers default color fill, white with opacity.
I need my polygon to be full transparent.
Any help?

[image: Image of polygon: Not truly transparent]

```
 var style = new ol.style.Style({

    fill: new ol.style.Fill({

      color:'transparent'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'white',
      width: 1
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

'transparent' is not a valid color. If you do not want a fill, simply don't configure a `fill` with your style:

```
var style = new ol.style.Style({
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: 'white',
    width: 1
  })
});
```

Comment: If you don't set a fill color, like you did, open layers sets the default color (white) with 0.1 opacity.

Comment: I did not set a fill at all, and that works as expected (i.e. the polygon will not be filled. See https://codepen.io/ahocevar/pen/MvyEQX. Please accept the answer if you agree.